# Perturbations of an operator that disconnect the spectrum 

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The following question came to me while working on a technical matter about transversality in infinite dimension, and I'm really curious to know whether it has an affirmative answer at least under extra hypotheses.

> Let A be a bounded linear operator on
>   a Banach space E. Does it exist a
>   bounded linear operator  S such that 0
>   and 1 do not belong to the same
>   connected component of the  spectrum
>   of the operator A<sub>S</sub>:= A + A(I-A)S?

That is, S is OK if either 0 or 1 is not in the spectrum of A<sub>S</sub>, or if they both are in the spectrum, they should belong to different connected component of it. Thus it may be assumed that 0 and 1 belong to the same component of spec(A), otherwise S=0 trivially solves the problem.

The first idea is to look for S of the form *f*(A), but this can't work if *f* is continuous,
since then spec(A<sub>S</sub>) is the continuous image of spec(A) with a map that fixes 0 and 1. However, if A admits a discontinuous functional calculus (e.g. a normal operator on Hilbert space), the trick does work.

I do not know the answer to the question even on Hilbert spaces. In a general Banach space the problem seems even harder, due the difficulty of building operators.

I'd very grateful of any suggestion! (Pietro Majer).

**edit (17/11/2011).**

Here are a few more or less trivial facts that I know.

- For a Banach space $X$, the set $\mathcal{A}$ of all $A\in L(X)$ such that there exists  $S\in L(X)$ such that no connected component of $\operatorname{spec}(A_S)$ contains both $0$ and $1$, is an open set;
- If $A\in \mathcal{A}$, then there is $S$ such that $A_S$ is even a linear projector (thus satifying the condition on the spectrum *ad abundantiam*);
- If $A\in L(X)$ and   $A_S\in \mathcal{A}$ for some $S\in  L(X)$, then $A$ itself is in $\mathcal{A}$;
- $A\in \mathcal{A}$ if and only if there are closed subspaces $V$ and $W$ of $X$ such that $V\times W\ni (v,w) \mapsto Av + (I-A)w \in X$ is bijective;
- if $AX$ is a closed subspace and $(I-A)^{-1}(AX)$ is a complemented subspace of $X$, then $A\in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: On the HI spaces of Gowers-Maurey every operator has countable spectrum, so at least this is true on some infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I'll mention it just in case: There is a classical theorem by Weyl-von Neumann that says: If A is a selfadjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space, then for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator S with Hilbert-Schmidt norm less than $\epsilon$ such that A+S has a pure point spectrum.

(Kato: "Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators", chapter 10, paragraph 2.1).

Unless I'm mistaken that answers the question for separable Hilbert spaces, no?

Comment: Tim: the result you quote is only for self-adjoint operators, which is already covered by the original poster's comment about normal operators.

Comment: Slight improvement : The conjecture is also true, if A is a compact perturbation of a normal operator. 

Comment: For me, only your first fact is "more or less trivial", Pietro.  

Comment: Then I will add details...

Comment: From fact 4 it follows, that the conjecture is true for every injective linear bounded operator on a Hilbert space H which has a closed range : 
choose V = H and W = $\mathcal{R}(A)^{\bot}$ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Hilbert spaces, the conjecture follows from fact 4 and the answer to question [Complement of a subspace which is a cartesian product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81652/complement-of-a-subspace-which-is-a-cartesian-product) applied to the kernel of the map $H\times H\ni (v,w) \mapsto Av + (I-A)w \in X$ .

Comment: that's true       !

Comment: I'm glad to accept this answer, as the case of Hilbert spaces is already quite interesting to me. 